# Do viewmodels need keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have my view model :

```
namespace projInterview.Models
{
    public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public piQuestion Question { get; set; }
        public List<piAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
        public piQuestionFavorite QuestionFavorite { get; set; }
        public piQuestionLevel QuestionLevel { get; set; }

        public QuestionViewModel(piQuestion question, List<piAnswer> answers )
        {
            Question = question;
            Answers = answers;
        }
    }
}
```

**The VM is a standalone class.  I did not scaffold this out to a controller.**

In my controller:

```
namespace projInterview.Controllers {
    public class QuestionController : Controller
    {
        private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            piQuestion piquestion = db.piQuestions.Single(x => x.QuestionID == id);

            List<piAnswer> piAnswers = db.piAnswers.Where((x => x.QuestionID == id)).ToList();
            var questionViewModel = new QuestionViewModel(piquestion,piAnswers);

            return View(questionViewModel); 
        } 
}
```

When I get to this line:

```
piQuestion piquestion = db.piQuestions.Single(x => x.QuestionID == id);
```

I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> projInterview.DAL.QuestionViewModel: : EntityType 'QuestionViewModel'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   questionViewModels: EntityType: EntitySet 'questionViewModels' is
>   based on type 'QuestionViewModel' that has no keys defined.

`piQuestion` and `piAnswer` both have keys in the original models that the viewmodel is using.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah.. you're doing it wrong. Did you map your viewmodels to your database? You can't do that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wait *wait* **wait**. A view model has absolutely nothing to do with an Entity framework context. It should not be associated with it. What you seem to have right now is that `db.piQuestions` is an `IQueryable<QuestionViewModel>` which is an absolutely wrong thing to do. A view model doesn't know anything about EF and EF doesn't know anything about view models.

NEVER map your view models to any database or EF stuff. What you put as `IQueryable<T>` properties to your DBContext are your Domain Models. Those are the models that are bound to your database tables.

Then in your controller action you make one or more calls to your database (DbContext) in order to retrieve one or more of those domain models. Then you map (copy the properties) of those domain models to a single view model. Finally you pass the view model to the view.

Also as a side remark, view models usually have default constructors. You don't need those specific constructors taking parameters. That will just make the default model binder insane if you attempt to have such view model as parameter to a controller action.

So to conclude: view models do not have any keys. They should not even know what a key is. A key is something specific to your Data Access Layer that is to say to your Domain Models.

Comment: This is great.  I need you to talk to a guy on my team that wants to basically use EF models all the way up through our WCF app stack.  Ie: EF model is the Entity Model, the DTO, and the ViewModel all in one.  *sigh*

Comment: I am afraid that I won't have the patience to talk to such guys :-) I hope (for you and your team) that the guy is not a decision maker.

Comment: @AaronPalmer, I think it's a good time to start looking for a better place to work.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Thanks for the response...  However, I'm still confused on how I'm supposed to set this up?  I didn't think that I did map my VM to the database.

Comment: @webdad3, you associate your domain models to a DbContext (a.k.a you make them properties of your DbContext). Your view model is a class that is completely dissociated from them. The view model should contain only properties that will be used in the view. Then in your controller action you query your DbContext to retrieve one or more domain models (in your case that would be questions and answers stuff). Once you have those domain models as instances you could copy the necessary properties to your view model.

Comment: But when we try to  scaffold a  view from the view model it also give the same error

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thats an awesome explanation. I don't have words to describe the eureka moment when I read that explanation. So simiplistic, yet covers the main details.

Answer (score 13):

For the sake of completion: when selecting a model in the View scaffolder, a domain model is expected, so it also pre-populates the Data context class and as such it expects a key. When selecting a viewmodel, simply delete the pre-filled DAL class and leave the DAL field blank.

[image: View Scaffolder]

If you actually define a key for a viewmodel, as I wrongly did, the scaffolder adds a definition of the viewmodel to the context class. To remedy the mess I had made, I deleted the viewmodel definitions from my context class and removed the keys from my viewmodels.

[I finally got the idea from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28789710/6021966)

Comment: This was my solution. Everything makes sense to me know, a view model has nothing to do with EF, why would we need a data context...

Comment: THanks, this is the real answer